# Viewing overall Fusion Tables account usage

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Fusion tables has a 1GB/account limit. I have been unable to figure out where to view my accounts usage thus far, where is this information?

Edit: The google developers console does not display this information.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your Google Cloud Console: 
Quota: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/fusiontables/quotas

If you have more than one project, make sure the desired project is selected in the top right of the window (in the blue header bar, there's a dropdown menu). Those links should get you to the general area.

**Edit:** The asker is correct in that Google Console does not have a location for an overall account usage or a tracking of bytes tranferred (Google just tracks API requests for Google Fusion Tables). The API limits are attached to each project rather than per Google account. You can view the quota of each API for an individual project on a single page: https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas?usage=ALL

Comment: This does not display what I'm looking for. This shows you your quotas and usage for requests, for that specific project. Not your total Fusion Table usage for your account. Accounts have a 1GB/account limit, this data does not seem to be displayed.